# i3: i3status - Network throughput

Tags: statusbar, network-traffic

I am new to i3 and would like to inquire if anyone knows how to show the combined traffic in Mbit/s running through (in and out) all network interfaces (ETH or WLAN) in real-time in the status bar?

I would like to do it via the config file if possible.

Comment: be more specific, what does it mean "all traffic running through interface". You want Mbit/s stats or Pkts/s ?

Comment: I am after a visual representation of the Mbit/s coming in and going out (similar to that of nload) however not the graph only the metric of traffic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use i3pystatus instead of plain i3status. It has a module for network and showing the metric, below is the relevant doc:

https://i3pystatus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#internet-connectivity

An example config with what you want is here:
https://i3pystatus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html

By changing `format_up` you can change which metric is shown.

Comment: If you want to stay with i3status you can use this wrapper provided in the contrib:
https://github.com/i3/i3status/blob/master/contrib/net-speed.sh